# How to make relation with two sheets in excel or Power BI dashboard

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

**Query :** How to make relation between the table. In Power BI, I need to create a dashboard with two bar charts, the first of which will display reports by category. Second, the chart will display the product-based report. However, in order to create an interactive main chart, I need to connect two sheets. If you click the corresponding category in the main chart, the second chart will be based on the first chart's selected category. How to do that?

Main Report:

[image]

**ProductWise Report:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to import data in separate sheet.

then just put categories to bar chart and remaining columns to other graph, Its automatically change.